# How to get previous data of model in forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

How to get previous data of model `TrustyRequest` field `status`. I need previous data of `status field` because of this condition

```
if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists() and status=='Accepted':
```

I want to see the previous state of `status` field and compare with current status which is being update - `status=='Accepted'`.

```
class TrustyRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TrustyRequest
        fields = [
            'masjid_name', 
            'masjid_address', 
            'first_name', 
            'last_name', 
            'email', 
            'phone_number',
            'status',
        ]

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        email = cleaned_data.get("email")
        status = cleaned_data.get("status")

        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists() and status=='Accepted':
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email Already Exists")
```

Comment: You may get the original value from `self.instance.status`.

Comment: Thanks it Worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get previous instance use `self.instance.status`